# XTK not displaying uncompressed DICOM in 2D render

Tags: xtk

I am trying to display some local DICOM / .dcm files with XTK in the 2D render model that are LUNG CT IMAGES from the RIDER dataset hosted on the cancer imaging archive and there are no errors thrown by the console but the images are being outputted as blank. The files and the relative links to the files in the js are correct but still no output.

I also did the "Developer Heads Up" build: https://github.com/xtk/X/wiki/X:DevelopersHeadsUp,
as well as trying to use the nightly build: https://github.com/xtk/get/blob/gh-pages/xtk_nightly.js.

```
    var _dicom = ['000008', '000009', '000010', '000011', '000012', '000013', '000014' , '000015' , '000016'];

      var r = new X.renderer2D();
      r.orientation = 'Z';
      r.init();
      var v = new X.volume();
      v.file = _dicom.sort().map(function(v) {
        return 'img/' + v + '.dcm';
      });
      r.add(v);

      r.onWindowLevel();
      r.render();
      $('canvas').attr('id', 'xtkCanvas');
      r.onShowtime = function() {
      };
      volume = v;
      };
```

I have also verified that the DICOM files are uncompressed by using OsiriX...

Comment: Do you have demo code somewhere or maybe throw it up on JSFiddle? I've been having similar problems with 3D volumes only showing on a 2D plane.

Comment: Here is a link to my Fiddle, the DICOM are being called from my dropbox, let know what you think. I can only get XTK to work with the images they provide from the babaymri link they have on the 3D fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/vZNGF/1/

Comment: I'm getting the cross domain error in Chrome console.  

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.dropbox.com/s/lmdsoabhmhj332g/000013.dcm. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Have you tried hosting it locally on your dev machine? I'm not sure how they got their cross domain babymri link to work.

Comment: Yea thats what I was doing primarily and they did not work as well. Not sure what the problem with the dicom is, it says it takes uncompressed dicoms and the ones I am using are from RIDER and when you open them in OsiriX it says they are uncompressed. NOt sure how they got the babymri to work either, but local dev finishes loading but the dicoms just show up as black...

Comment: I just used your code and changed the dicom data to mine and it worked fine in firefox and chrome. So when your progress bar loads and everything? Once loaded try rolling the scroll wheel on the mouse and nothing is displayed? Scroll wheel should scroll through each dicom image. Also are you using xtk_edge or xtk? My test used xtk.js

Comment: Well then it must be my data then... Yea I tried just about everything concerning the user actions with xtk. I am also using xtk.js, and tried the new build option they suggested as well. Well I guess it must just be the data then that is the problem maybe I could get a link to some of the data you are using and compare it side by side with the RIDER dicoms to see what is different about the two types of dicoms.